# error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'std::_Ios_Openmode'|

Tags: c++, sockets

I'm trying to use [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/client_server_socket.aspx) C++ class as a base for my own application's client/server communication. But it's throwing an error I do not understand, it's inside **myLog.cpp**.

`error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'std::_Ios_Openmode'|`

Which is here:

```
void myLog::openLog(const string& fileName, int mode)
{
   if (logLevel < QUIET_MODE)
   {
      open(fileName.c_str(),mode); //Error line
      /* SNIP */
```

Which is called here:

```
void myLog::init()
{
   openLog("syslog.log",LOG_WRITE);
}
```

And LOG_WRITE is defined in the header like so:

```
const int LOG_WRITE  = ios::out;
```

Can anybody tell me why this is happening?

Quick link to code: [myLog.cpp](http://pastebin.com/B9F0JAt3) -- [myLog.h](http://pastebin.com/0SBxDzZb)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ios::out` isn't `int` but `std::_Ios_Openmode`.

Comment: +1 - I guess `std::_ios_Openmode` is a typedef of [`std::ios_base::openmode`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios_base/openmode/) which should be used for portable code.

Comment: I ended up completely removing the logging feature in that code, because the whole thing was made under the assumption that it was `int`. I don't understand why the compiled example they provide has a working logging feature...

Comment: @natli Because at some time, on some compiler `std::ios_base::openmode` was `int` (most likely MSVC).

Answer (score 2):

This has already been answered. However, for people using the logging tool in question, do the following:

In the header change:

```
    const int LOG_WRITE  = ios::out;
    const int LOG_APPEND = ios::app;
```

to

```
    const std::ios_base::openmode LOG_WRITE  = std::ios::out;
    const std::ios_base::openmode LOG_APPEND = std::ios::app;
```

Change the Init functions from `int` to `std::ios_base::openmode`, e.g.

```
    ..., std::ios_base::openmode mode)
```

Using int worked with OSX but failed with RHEL 5.10. Once I made the above change, it worked on RHEL 5.10.

OSX:

```
$ gcc -v
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0
Thread model: posix
```

RHEL 5.10:

```
$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.8.3/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Configured with: /SDK/GCC/objdir/../gcc-4.8.3/configure
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.3 (GCC)
```

On OSX the type is defined as:

```
typedef unsigned int openmode;
typedef openmode     open_mode;
static const openmode app    = 0x01;
static const openmode ate    = 0x02;
static const openmode binary = 0x04;
static const openmode in     = 0x08;
static const openmode out    = 0x10;
static const openmode trunc  = 0x20;
```